# How do i insert data parent table and child table same time?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im trying to insert data into mysql using codeIgniter framework when when i try it will showing this error

```
    Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pslsystem`.`invoice_description`, CONSTRAINT `invoice_description_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reference_no`) REFERENCES `myinvoice` (`reference_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

INSERT INTO `invoice_description` (`reference_no`, `description`) VALUES (6, 'description1')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/pslsystem/application/models/sample_model.php

Line Number: 21
```

This is my two tables :

```
CREATE TABLE myinvoice (
    invoice_id INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invoice_type  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    reference_no varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    des_title varchar(300) NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id, reference_no)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE invoice_description(
 des_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 reference_no varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 description varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (des_id,reference_no),
 FOREIGN KEY (reference_no) REFERENCES myinvoice (reference_no) on delete cascade ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

here is my model

```
function insert_entry($data1, $data2) {

    $this->db->insert('myinvoice', $data1);

    $data2['reference_no'] = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('invoice_description', $data2);
}
```

Here is My controller:

```
if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->model('sample_model');
            $data1 = array(
                  'invoice_type' => $this->input->post('type'),
                  'reference_no' => $this->input->post('ref'),
                  'des_title' => $this->input->post('title'),

                  );

        $data2 = array(
            'reference_no' => $this->input->post('ref'),
             'description' => $this->input->post('des'),
        );

             $this->sample_model->insert_entry($data1,$data2);



        }else{

            $this->load->view('sample_view');
        }
```

when i try to insert parent table data only inserting. and shoing this error.

Comment: as per your code, foreign key constraint should be on invoice_id and after seeing your query, it seem parent table insertion did not return integer and need to check that also. I also suggesting you to modify table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to insert `reference_no` into `invoice_description` two times
Once you set in in your controler code

```
$data2 = array(
            'reference_no' => $this->input->post('ref'),
             'description' => $this->input->post('des'),
        );
```

And second in your model

```
$this->db->insert('myinvoice', $data1);
$data2['reference_no'] = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Just remove

```
 $data2['reference_no'] = $this->db->insert_id();
```

This from your model because this the last inserted id not your `reference_no`

Comment: Thank you @Saty i just remove that code its works perfect :) and one more thing i want ur help in my **invoice_desctrption** table i want add multiple rows for single **ref_no** i knw we need to use **forech loop** but i dont knw how to use :( meanz add dynamic fileds**_ (description)_** thrw that insert mutiple row i knw how to add dynamic filed but i donw how to use foreach loop here...... :(

Comment: [this is the link try to help me ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200658/how-to-insert-arrays-into-mysql-using-codeigniter)